# Is this relation holds? l ⊨ ∀ u ( u < y) ∨ ( u * z < y ∗ z)

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I am trying to show that below relation holds

$$l  ⊨ ∀ u ( u < y) ∨ ( u * z < y ∗  z)$$

The values for the above relation are

$$  l(x) = -2$$
  $$  l(y) = 5$$
  $$  l(z) = -1$$

$l  ⊨ ∀u ( u < y) ∨ ( u * z < y ∗  z)$  holds; for u being $4, l ⊨ ( u < y)$ holds, but $l ⊨ ( u * z < y ∗  z)$  does not hold. However, $T ∨ F$ evaluates to $T$. So the relation holds.

Is that enough explanation?

Also, what does  ∀u mean exactly?

Comment: x, z and y are integers so i thought u should be integer

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it holds.